# XKB: Can I have an eight-level key and have Ctrl participate in selecting it’s levels?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

Is there an XKB way to generate a key event, form a normal key combo which includes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> without having the ctrl modifier bit set?

Or the same question asked in another way: Can I have an eight-level key, where apart from <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> participates in level selection and `XLookupString()` does not make a control character out of it??

I want to type something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and get a “c“ as a result of `XLookupString()` (as an example). I want this to be the exceptional result of an eight-level key type. The other keys should work normally (with two or four levels only).

(The problem is that XLookupString() interpretes the ctrl modifier bit itself, generating control characters even for keysyms which have no “corresponding control character”.)

Actually, there is a way: with the redirect action in the XKB configuration.

So the question is: is there another (“better”) way of doing it? Or does someone have experience with redirecting to the key itself, removing the modifier bit, but still selecting e.g. the fifth level of eight levels of keysyms?